# I have a doubt about my text's calculation of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt[4]{1-4x^2+x^4} -1+x^2}{x^4}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a doubt about the calculation of a limit in my book.
I have this limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt[4]{1-4x^2+x^4} -1+x^2}{x^4}$$

In my book it is said that $\sqrt[4]{1-t} \approx 1+ \frac{1}{4}t$ and then $\sqrt[4]{1-4x^2+x^4} \approx 1-x^2+\frac{1}{4}x^4$

I agree with $\sqrt[4]{1-t} \approx 1+ \frac{1}{4}t$ but when I do the derivative of $\sqrt[4]{1-4x^2+x^4} $ it is $\frac{1}{4}(1-4x^2+x^4)^{-\frac{3}{3}} \cdot (-8x+4x^3)$ and its value in $x=0$ is $0$ and not $\frac{1}{4}$,

while in the book the expression $-4x^2+x^4$ is merely put in the formulas without considering the fact that we have to do the derivative.

The calculation is not still good and we have to consider another term of the development to have the right value of the limit. Also in this case the book continues in this way. I've tried with wolfram alpha and actually the book is right, so there is something that I don't understand .
Can someone explain why I'm making mistakes? I'm not very good with this argument of Taylor development

Comment: Recall that $f'(0)$ is the coefficient of $x$ in the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$. So you calculated that $f'(0)=0$. What's the coefficient of $x$ in $1-x^2 + \tfrac14 x^4$? Also $0$. So there is no contradiction there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example from your book is not precise, and draws some accurate conclusions and some inaccurate ones.

If your $\approx$ were actually $=$, then the book's conclusion would be obviously correct. You're just substituting $t=-x^2+\tfrac14 x^4$ into both sides of an equation. The unstated analogy is that while substituting the same thing on both sides preserves equality, it should also preserve *approximate* equality. To prove whether that's actually true or not requires a bit more about what approximate equality means.

The error in the approximation $\sqrt[4]{1+t} \approx 1+\tfrac14 t$ (which I guess is what you meant) is said to be "of order $t^2$". That means that the error in the approximation is proportional to $t^2$, as long as $t$ is sufficiently close to $0$. It follows that

$$\sqrt[4]{1-4x^2+x^4} \approx 1-x^2+\tfrac14x^4$$
with an error proportional to $(-4x^2 + x^4)^2$, which itself is proportional to $x^4$ when $x$ is small. This means that we can be sure that the terms up to $x^3$ in the expansion above are accurate, but not $x^4$ or higher. In fact, we can use the approximation:

$$\sqrt[4]{1+t} \approx 1+\tfrac14t - \tfrac{3}{32}t^2$$
which has error proprtional to $t^3$, to deduce that the $x^4$ coefficient should *actually* be $\tfrac14 - 16 \cdot\tfrac{3}{32} = -\tfrac54$, which is the true value of your limit.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an expansion of the fourth root via the binomial theorem, up to order $2$:
$$\sqrt[4]{1+u} =1+\tfrac14u -\tfrac 3{32} u^2+o(u^2),$$
and subsituting $u=-4x^2+x^2$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\sqrt[4]{1-4x^2+x^4}&=1+\tfrac14(-4x^2+x^4)-\tfrac 3{32}(-4x^2+x^4)^2+o(x^4)\\
&=1-x^2 -\tfrac 54x^4+o(x^4),
\end{align}
whence
$$\frac{\sqrt[4]{1-4x^2+x^4} -1+x^2}{x^4}=\frac{-\frac54 x^4+o(x^4)}{x^4}=\color{red}{-\frac54}+o(1).$$